# Why array does not print list?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i;
    char s[10] = {'a' , 'b' ,'c' 'd' ,'e', 'f', 'g', 'g','h','i'};

    cout << "element" << setw(7) << "value " << endl;
    for (i=0 ; i <10 ; i++)
    cout << i << setw(7) << s[i] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I Wanted tp get list like

```
element       value
0              a
1              b
2              c
3              d
4              e
5              f  
6              g
7              g
8              h
9              i
```

but compiler gives error....
Is there anyone who can point out my error?

Comment: You're the one who needs to point out your error and then we'll tell you what the problem is.

Comment: Read the error message closely, and it will show you where you forgot a comma.

Comment: You're missing another comma: `'c' 'd' `

Comment: the compiler is more often than not able to *point out your error*, and it has done so... you need to learn how to read compiler error messages. For that, try to interpret what it says and if you cannot make heads from tails, add it in a question for people with more experience to help you understand it.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a compiler; use a compiler to help you find the syntax error.

Comment: If you do not like to answer questions don't.There are people who don't mind for questions.Check answers of others.I really thanx to all of them.I will be carefull in future to avoid put questions on forum having syntax error.

Comment: This gives me a bunch of weird errors, but only one actually is. You should read, and fix, errors from the first reported one to the last - the first error can give rise to a cascade of other errors. For a beginner it's probably a good idea to pretend that only the first error actually exists. I get "expected '}' before 'd'", which isn't a good description of the actual problem but points at exactly the right place.

Comment: @SohailAhmed: We don't mind _questions_, but this is not a _question_. It's laziness. You didn't even tell us what the error is!!! Questions on SO must be able to help somebody else some day, and this one does not fit into that category. "If you do not like to answer questions don't" is thus an irrelevant and vacuous statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in the initializer list. You forgot to place a comma

```
char s[10] = {'a' , 'b' ,'c' 'd' ,'e', 'f', 'g', 'g','h','i'};
                          ^^^^
```